# .NET API for SQL Server Service Broker

Tags: .net, sql-server, service-broker

Is there a .NET API or object model for using SQL Server Service Broker?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't an official supported API. There are some community samples though which are developed by the Service Broker team or related teams in MS which you can use as a starting point, but they are not officially supported (you cannot call product support and report a bug).

Answer (score 5):

Checkout this file: https://github.com/jdaigle/servicebroker.net/blob/893a2d9c6a6ef6aed9c1d05dc6a253183a5d7470/ServiceBrokerDotNet/ServiceBrokerWrapper.cs

It's a small wrapper around the T-SQL calls that I wrote. The community samples that other mentioned are more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: It's been a while, but I've been looking for the file you mentioned and I cannot find it, would you mind offering another link?

Answer (score 1):

A easy to use queue library for SQL Service Broker based on rhino-queues

http://github.com/CoreyKaylor/servicebroker-queues

Answer (score 0):

I just found a managed library sample ([Readme_HelloWorld_CLR Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160848.aspx)) and a complete T-SQL reference here: [SQL Server Service Broker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx).