# Wait operation Time Out: 2 projects, same database, heavy load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, timeout

We have two projects which are using the same database.

As one of the projects undergoes an heavy database operation, the other may do small `Task` requests like these:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetManaIconAsync(string _mana)
{
    string mana = _mana.Replace("/", "");

    byte[] imageData = await Task.Run<byte[]>(() => mImateManager.GetManaByName(mana));

    return File(imageData, "image/png");
}

public byte[] GetManaByName(string _mana)
{
    using (MyDb db = new MyDb())
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Open();

        IQueryable<ITEM_IMAGES> imageQry = from img in db.ITEM_IMAGES
                       where img.ITEM_IMAGE_TYPE == (int)ImageTypes.Mana
                       select img;

        if (!imageQry.Any())
        {
            return null;
        }

        return imageQry.First(_item => _item.ITEM_NAME == _mana).ITEM_IMAGE;
    }
}
```

And project2 would crash when hitting the `if(!imageQry.AnY())` saying that the wait operation timed out, which is normal since project1 is currently doing heavy work.

Now my question is how could I solve this? What are the options available so that both may do their respective work without impacting (too much) the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL service broker might be an option for you. Please review: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166071(v=sql.105).aspx and tell me if this could work for your scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly what is a Service Broker. Correct me if I'm wrong: it will take any queries / task I send to it, then proceed with the tasks asynchronously while resuming the main program, so project A may do its heavy load and project B would be able to make its query calls and everything would be treated separately?

Comment: That is correct. You can send the heavy requests asynchronously to the service broker and in turn connect with application B to the database. Take a look at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576261(v=sql.100).aspx for some more details about scalability or might want to search for an article specific for throttling the service broker

Comment: Please make sure to mark the response as answered when it helped you're case. Happy coding!

Comment: I'll explore it, do you know any area where I might get a tutorial / example for this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/a508ffc9-aed0-43a4-912e-0347782f5671/service-broker-and-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089184/net-api-for-sql-service-broker